# execCommand Customization

Tags: javascript

With execCommand different browsers create different code. firefox might take span and set the font-weight , IE decides to write tag strong or p.
Here is a link for execCommand demos.
http://help.dottoro.com/ljcvtcaw.php

Is there anyway to customize the code that execCommand generates?
Is there any command like execCommand  which can generate same code in all browsers?

Comment: You can customize `execCommand` or any other method by modifying `document`'s prototype. However, the implementation of `execCommand`'s command are mostly can only be done by the browser's internal functions which are browser-specific and most have no equivalent DOM/HTML methods. For example, the `SaveAs` IE command. But you can add a custom command like "MsgBox" that will execute the `alert` method.

Answer (score 1):

I would just build multiple arrays for multiple functions and when a user is complete with their file, just run a `.replace();`